# achieve google books like function with c# MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to code an MVC application similar to Google books in C#, where users can only read on-line and cannot copy or download or print. Are there any other ways to achieve this? So far from my research on Google I learnt that if user can view a book on his browser he can download/copy/print because its not in server control and browser functions cannot be changed from code. What are the things I can do to fulfil my requirements? Your help is appreciated, Thanks.

I found a site doing above things. It won't let user download/print unless he is a valid subscribed member. My needs are similar to this. http://www.scribd.com/doc/85019258/WCF-Complete-Material

Comment: you can achieve to your goal by JavaScript tricks and it doesn't depend on the server side language or framework! overall you can do

Comment: @Ehsan, Thanks Ehsan but I was expecting a bit more specific answer. Even though something can be done by javascript user still can see book content in page source.

Comment: try this one http://sandrinodimattia.net/blog/posts/consuming-google-reader-with-net-part-2-google-reader-using-net/ you can also use google reader Api https://sites.google.com/site/ursuleacv/knowledge/google-reader-api